# Phonegap Cordova installation Windows

Tags: windows, cordova

The documentation for phonegap/cordova is absolutely horrible.  All I'm trying to do is install PhoneGap 3.0 on my Windows environment but having no success.

Below are my steps and points of failure.  Can anyone advise on solutions?

According to the [instructions](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.0.0/guide_cli_index.md.htm):

1. Install Node.js (SUCCESSFUL)
2. From nodes.js: `install -g cordova` (SUCCESSFUL)
3. Add Platform: `cordova platform add wp8` (NOTHING HAPPENS)
4. Try with phonegap: `phonegap install wp8` (ERROR project directory could not be found)

From "[Windows Phone 8 platform guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_platforms_wp8_index.md.html#Windows%20Phone%208%20Platform%20Guide)"

1. Install Windows SDK (SUCCESSFUL)
2. "Download and extract the latest copy of [PhoneGap. You will be working in the lib\windows-phone-8\wp8 subfolder, lib\windows-phone-8\wp7 contains the Windwos Phone 7 version of Cordova"

HUH?!?!  What location is the directory in?!?!  So I've found the undocumented phonegap directory buried in AppData\Local... and there IS a libs directory but there certainly is NOT any WP8 subfolders.  Where would one install that from?  Presumably the add platform command above, but add that simply returns me to a new command prompt.

Tried using the phonegap command: `phonegap plaform add wp8`

ERROR - 'platform add wp8" is not a node.

I get its open source but this is brutal spaghetti reference documentation.  If anyone has been able to successfully install 3.0 for WP8 any pointers would be help.

Comment: It mentions that you need to create the app with `cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld` in the directory that you want the code to be in, and then run `cordova platform add wp8` in the project directory that you just created.

Comment: I couldn't agree more, I've just pissed away 6 hrs of my weekend trying to make it work too.I've used it in the past and setting it up then wasn't hard at all but the 'new improved' cli way of doing things just doesn't work with the provided instructions. The first part tells you to install and use the phonegap command and then you move on to the android section and it switches to using the cordova command. What a frustratrating mess, I never did figure out how to get it to recognize the android platform even though the sdk was installed on my machine.

Comment: The quality of the writing doesn't bother me as much as the fact that the docs never appear to have been tested and are just wrong.

Comment: It seems also like the documentation is contradictory in places.  On one page it says to do it one way and on another it describes an entirely different approach!  I had things nice with the Phonegap extension part of my Android Developer Tools as a button (in Eclipse).  Now, after upgrading the ADT it is gone.  I ran the phonegap platform add android and got nothing to happen like above with wp8.  Why can't we just download it as a zip?  Or use git clone?

Comment: I wrote an article providing a step by step instruction on how to install phonegap. It is tailored to Android devices, but the only difference should be the Windows/Android SDK part: http://kapitanh.blogspot.de/2014/02/native-android-apps-with.html

Comment: I've wasted hours trying to figure out how to set up the environment wasting tons of bandwidth but yet no success.

Answer (score 133, accepted):

After hours of frustration... here's what i discovered.

1. **Ignore the installation documentation** and all the command line, node.js stuff (seriously you will waste hours on this.
2. Go to github and simply download the [PhoneGap master .zip](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/archive/master.zip)
3. In that zip are project files for window phone, etc platform... just use those templates.

I don't know how such an easy process could have worse documentation.  It as if it was written by lawyers.

Comment: Using the documentation would have permitted you to have one "global" `www` folder for all platforms.

Comment: Thanks for this, saved me a lot of aggravation, I'm sure.  Also, this is an excellent resource for anyone setting up Phonegap for Android: [link](http://cookieflow.wordpress.com/2013/02/24/installing-android-4-2-sdk-and-phonegap-2-4-0-on-windows-7/)

Comment: Are you serious? Is this for real? I don't know whether to be really angry or very happy. Will I be able to add plugins without the command-line too? And is this still valid for the very-different Phonegap 3.0?

Comment: Frigon your description is excellent but you should mention that createTemplates.bat should be executed to generate the zip files that are the stuff to be copied to the templates folder.

Comment: Hexodus, it doesn't seem that this step is documented anywhere, or at least it is not very clear at all.  As one can imagine, starting on one page with running a cordova command and then being taken to another page that says use phonegap, or is it the other way?, is very confusing.  Oliver, your link is great, the page is very clear.  But I almost overlooked the link.  I started thinking, "what is an excellent resource?"  Then I stumbled upon the link and found the excellent resource.  Respectfully, I'd suggest that everything from excellent resource up to link be the link, IMHO.

Comment: Last year(2012) this is how I used to install phonegap.I'm not sure on what's the difference in using the command line since the documentation does not explain there difference.

Comment: iup but from https://github.com/apache/cordova-android#building where is the cordova installation inside there is not so cordova 3.2.jar so this way how can we build path?

Comment: how to add cordova plugin without cli?

Comment: npm list -g

npm rm phonegap
npm cache clear

npm install -g phonegap

Comment: For android which template do I need to use? There bin, fremework and test directories, also in those directories many files and directories included.

Comment: @Dear All: Can any body please guide in detail how to use this `phonegap-master.zip` for android on windows 7?

Comment: Sorry, but this no longer works.  Downloading phonegap-master.zip from your link results in three files in a folder.  There's a .gitignore, a LICENSE file and finally, a README.MD and nothing more.

Comment: @MichaelBlankenship that's true. This method no longer works as there are no 'useful' files in that zip. Guess its an old archive...

Answer (score 55):

I faced the same problem and struggled for an hour to get pass through by reading [the documents](http://docs.phonegap.com/) and the other issues reported in Stack Overflow but I didn't find any answer to it. So, here is the guide to successfully run the phonegap/cordova in Windows Machine.

### Follow these steps

1. Download and Install node.js from http://nodejs.org/
2. Run the command `npm install -g phonegap` (in case of phonegap installation) or run the command `npm install -g cordova` (in case of Cordova installation).
3. As the installation gets completed you can notice this:

   ```
   C:\Users\binaryuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\cordova -> C:\Users\binaryuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\bin\cordova
   cordova@3.0.9 C:\Users\binaryuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova
   ├── ncallbacks@1.0.0
   ├── open@0.0.3
   ├── colors@0.6.2
   ├── semver@1.1.0
   ├── shelljs@0.1.2
   ├── follow-redirects@0.0.3 (underscore@1.5.2)
   ├── elementtree@0.1.3 (sax@0.3.5)
   ├── optimist@0.6.0 (wordwrap@0.0.2, minimist@0.0.2)
   ├── xcode@0.5.1 (node-uuid@1.3.3, pegjs@0.6.2)
   ├── glob@3.2.6 (inherits@2.0.1, minimatch@0.2.12)
   ├── plist@0.4.3 (xmlbuilder@0.4.2, xmldom@0.1.16)
   ├── tar@0.1.18 (inherits@2.0.1, block-stream@0.0.7, fstream@0.1.24)
   ├── prompt@0.2.7 (revalidator@0.1.5, pkginfo@0.3.0, read@1.0.5, utile@0.1.7, winston@0.6.2)
   ├── request@2.22.0 (json-stringify-safe@4.0.0, aws-sign@0.3.0, qs@0.6.5, oauth-sign@0.3.0, forever-agent@0.5.0, cookie-jar@0.3.0, tunnel-agent@0.3.0, mime@1.2.11, node-uuid@1.4.1, http-signature@0.10.0, hawk@0.13.1, form-data@0.0.8)
   ├── express@3.0.0 (methods@0.0.1, fresh@0.1.0, range-parser@0.0.4, crc@0.2.0, cookie@0.0.4, commander@0.6.1, debug@0.7.2, mkdirp@0.3.3, send@0.1.0, connect@2.6.0)
   ├── ripple-emulator@0.9.18 (connect-xcors@0.5.2, colors@0.6.0-1, accounting@0.3.2, request@2.12.0, moment@1.7.2, express@3.1.0)
   ├── npm@1.3.11
   └── plugman@0.11.0 (ncallbacks@1.1.0, osenv@0.0.3, bplist-parser@0.0.4, underscore@1.4.4, semver@2.0.11, dep-graph@1.1.0, elementtree@0.1.5, xcode@0.6.1, nopt@1.0.10, rc@0.3.0, tar.gz@0.1.1, npm@1.3.4)
   ```
4. Notice the above line you can see the path were the file is mentioned. Copy that path. In my case it is `C:\Users\binaryuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\cordova` so use `cd C:\Users\binaryuser\AppData\Roaming\npm\` and type `cordova`. There it is, it finally works.
5. Since the `-g` key value isn't working you have set the Environment Variables path:

   1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>Pause|Break</kbd> or right click on `Computer` and choose `Properties`.
   2. Click `Advanced system settings` on the left.
   3. Click `Environment Variables` under the `Advanced` tab.
   4. Select the `PATH` variable and click `Edit`.
   5. Copy the path mentioned above to the value field and press `OK`.

Comment: Also note that if you install node.js as an Administrator, and your user has limited rights under Active Directory, you should run "npm install -g phonegap" as your user and not as an administrator, or else files will be created under administrator's roaming folder and your user will not have access to them. You can "npm uninstall phonegap" under administrator, and again install as your user in that case.

Comment: Note, you need to use the `Node.js command prompt`, not the built in Windows cmd.exe

Comment: @gotnull I second your motion.

Comment: When I tried to use the node.js command prompt I was given an error that directed me to use the system terminal.  This is for Node.js v0.10.26.

Comment: This answer tell exactly what is in the official instructions, which works, but this doesn't answer the wp8 templates part. The wp8 folder nor the createTemplates.bat file can not be found when installing cordova/phonegap with npm, which is mainly the point of the question.

Answer (score 18):

### This answer was first posted here: [cordova/phonegap does not make android directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18923720/cordova-phonegap-does-not-make-android-directory/18971442#18971442)

With the release of Cordova 3.3.0, it seems the PhoneGap team is trying to address the naming confusion. The documentations have been updated to recommend people using the `cordova` command instead. Do not use the <strike>`phonegap`</strike> command anymore.

Here is a fresh installation guide for a guaranteed trouble free set up:

1. Install Cordova (forget the name PhoneGap from now on). 
   For PC:

   ```
   C:> npm install -g cordova
   ```
2. From command prompt, navigate to the folder you want to create your project using:

   ```
   cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
   cd hello
   ```
3. Define the OS you want to suppport for example:

   ```
   cordova platform add wp8
   ```
4. Install plugins (If needed). For example we want the following:

   ```
   cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
   cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera
   cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.media-capture
   cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.media
   ```
5. Finally, generate the app using:

   ```
   cordova build wp8
   ```

Here is a link to the <strike>PhoneGap</strike>Cordova 3.3.0 Documentation
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.3.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface

Comment: Also, did you get the build command working? I can build in Visual Studio but not from command line. Error: `D:\Project1\platforms\wp8\cordova\lib\build.js(56, 5) WshShell.Exec: The system cannot find the file specified.` Not sure what file it is looking for.

Comment: On line 56 you will find `Log("Command: " + command);` commented out. Uncommenting it will print out `command`, and you will know what file it’s looking for.

Comment: In step#2, I believe it should be "cd hello", instead of "cd HelloWorld" .

Answer (score 6):

I faced this same error too.
And i even tried downloading the PhoneGap master from GitHub,but i found out that what i got was Phonegap 2.9.
I eventually had to download the [Cordova 3 Source](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/cordova/cordova-3.0.0-src.zip)

Follow this steps to get it.

1. Download and unzip the [Cordova 3 Source](https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/cordova/cordova-3.0.0-src.zip)
2. Run the template.bat in the cordova-wp8 folder
3. Copy the generated Zip files to your Visual studio template folder

Answer (score 4):

[Phonegap Cordova Installation  on Windows](http://tutsinstitute.com/phonegap-cordova-installation/)

**Requirements**

- Eclipse + ADT Plugin
- Android SDK Tool
- Android Platform Tools
- Latest PhoneGap zip folder. Extract its contents.

**Supported Android Devices**

Android 2.2
Android 2.3
Android 4.x
Phonegap Cordova Installation

Set PATH environment variable for android

1. From desktop, right click My Computer and click Properties.
2. Click Advance System Settings link in the left column.
3. In the system properties window click the environment variables button.
4. Select the PATH variable from the System variables section.
   Select the Edit button.
   You need to add the path to your Android SDK platform-tools and tools directory. For Example:
   D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219\sdk\platform-tools;D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219\sdk\tools
   Save your Edit. Close the Environment Variable dialog.
5. Additionally, you may need to include %JAVA_HOME%\bin to your PATH as well. To check to see if this is required run a command prompt and type java. If the program could not be found add %JAVA_HOME%\bin to the PATH. You may need to specify the full path instead of using %JAVA_HOME% environment variable.
6. Finally, you may need to include %ANT_HOME%\bin to your PATH as well. To check to see if this is required run a command prompt and type ant. If program cannot be found then add %ANT_HOME%\bin to the PATH. You may need to specify the full path instead of using the %ANT_HOME% environment variable.
   Set-up New Project

Open Command Prompt, navigate to bin directory within the android sub-folder of the Cordova distribution.

Type in:  ./create

Then press Enter.Launch Eclipse. In File Menu Item and select to Import…

Import Select “Existing Android Code into Workspace” and click ‘Next >’.

Browse the project created through command prompt. And click ‘Finish’.
Deploy to Emulator
From within Eclipse, press this toolbar icon.

Once open, the Android SDK Manager displays various runtime libraries
Install the APIs as per requirement from here.
From within Eclipse, press this toolbar icon.

Choose and device definition from the list which comes. (There is only one item in the current list.)
Press New… in the above window to create new Android Virtual Device(AVD) and use it to run your project.

To open the emulator as a separate application, Select the AVD and press Start. It launches much as it would on device, with additional controls available for hardware buttons:

Deploy to Device:

Make sure USB debugging is enabled on your device and plug it into your system.
Right Click the Project and go to Run As > Android Application.

[Read more ...](http://tutsinstitute.com/phonegap-cordova-installation/)

Answer (score 2):

In `C:\phonegap-2.9.0\lib\windows-phone-8 there's` a batch file called `createTemplates.bat`. You need to execute this file, which will create the `CordovaWP8_2_9_0.zip` file mentioned in their docs.

Comment: I am not able to find this batch file for phonegap-3.3.0. I n fact I am not able to find windows-phone-8 folder. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I was having issues wtih installing phonegap. The issues were fixed when i run cmd as Administrator and then run command

```
npm install -g phonegap
```

and it is installed successfully.

Then in the directory where it is installed i opened cmd, and run command phonegap and it was working fine. 
Now going to play with it more :)

Thanks buddies for all this help.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue but finally i got success by doing this please go throw this image
Plase Run all the command in the **PHONE TOOL COMMAND PROMPT**
[image]

Comment: Hi Mayur. I try with your above method. I got error in add platform . after i type cordova platform add wp8. following error occur   Error: Could not find 'check_reqs.js' in 'bin' folder, aborting...

Comment: @mayur - also doesnt work for me. I get 'cordova' is not recognized, blah, blah, blah. A path problem I assume. But where is cordova?

Answer (score 1):

I have found this 
[Multi-Device Hybrid Apps for Visual Studio Documentation for CTP1.1 Last updated: May 29, 2014](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=42675) .

Some of the content from the documentation as follows.

This release supports building apps for the following **device targets**:

**Android 4+ (4.4 providing the optimal developer experience)
iOS 6 & 7
Windows 8.0 (Store)
Windows Phone 8.0**

**Requirements:**
Windows 8.1

Visual Studio 2013 Update 2 - Professional, Ultimate, or Premium with the following optional features installed:

Tools for Maintaining Store apps for Windows 8
Windows Phone 8.0 SDK

**Additional system requirements vary by device platform:**

The Android emulator works best with PCs capable of installing the Intel HAXM driver

Windows Phone 8 requires a Hyper-V capable PC to run the emulator
Building for iOS and using the iOS Simulator requires a Mac capable of running Xcode 5.1

**Third Party Dependencies :**

Joyent Node.js – Enables Visual Studio to integrate with the Apache Cordova Command Line Interface (CLI) and Apache Ripple™ Emulator
Git CLI – Required only if you need to manually add git URIs for plugins

Google Chrome – Required to run the Apache Ripple emulator for iOS and Android

Apache Ant 1.8.0+ – Required as a dependency for the Android build process

Oracle Java JDK 7 – Required as a dependency for the Android build process

Android SDK – Required as a dependency for the Android build process and Ripple

SQLLite for Windows Runtime – required to add SQL connectivity to Windows apps (for the WebSQL Polyfill plugin)

Apple iTunes – Required for deploying an app to an iOS device connected to your Windows PC

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Running the CMD as Administrator on Windows got me going and I think it only makes perfect sense because people don't really ever make an effort to install their stuff in a custom directory. So when you install node.js in Windows directory and then try to install PhoneGap on a Unelevated CMD it has a hard time setting the path variables.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I lost hours, then I saw that version of node.js installed was 0.8. But I downloaded and installed version 0.10 from node.js website.

I downloaded and installed again, and now version is 0.10. Result: PhoneGap has been sucessfully installed with this version.

Answer (score 0):

Phonegap can be a little tricky for freshers. I spent much time trying to find the optimum way for creating a robust android application which can access the phone's native features.

[This link](http://aakshays.blogspot.in/2015/03/building-your-first-phonegapcordova.html) provides a step wise method for creating a Phonegap android application using windows, html and javascript.

Answer (score -5):

I too struggled a lot with phonegap  steps.

The correct documentation is at the following link. 
  http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_cli_index.md.html

There is no more cordova command, It is replaced with phonegap.