# Cannot find CordovaWP8xx_x.zip after installing phonegap

Tags: cordova

I am trying to setup visual studio to edit phonegap project. I installed phonegap.

I cannot locate CordovaWP8xx_x.zip listed in the instruction.

Comment: Did you download the latest version from the PhoneGap site?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035566/phonegap-cordova-installation-windows?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

You have to double click on the CreateTemplates Batch file in the lib/windows-phone-8 folder.

It's a step missing in the documentation...