# PhoneGap 3.1.0 without node / npm and command line tools

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins

Is it possible to download and consume PhoneGap 3.1.0 without node package.  Having a restricted network connection, its annoying to install node, PhoneGap module, Cordova module and plugin's from git hub command lines.

Consuming PhoneGap 2.9 seems to be so easy and simple.  Can we download PhoneGap 3.1 as like 2.9 without these dependencies?

Is there any direct download link for 3.1 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Cordova 3.1 instead:
[Download](https://www.apache.org/dist/cordova/cordova-3.1.0-src.zip)

[You can compare this Stackoverflow question and Layinkas answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035566/phonegap-cordova-installation-windows)

Comment: Is there any working link?
The link you mentioned is expired i need these files

Answer (score 1):

Nope, sorry. PhoneGap use node's package manager for other things too, so you can't bypass this (to my knowledge).

See http://phonegap.com/install/