# Database fails to open in phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, android-sqlite

I am trying to execute phonegap example where it should create database and create tables. I am trying to execute from below link
      http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.4.1/phonegap_storage_storage.md.html#Storage

below is my code

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>Contact Example</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-1.4.1.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
 function datab()
 {
  alert("i m in db");
  var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
  db.transaction(function (tx) {
  tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS LOGSS');
  tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS file1 (id unique, log1 , log2)');
  tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO file1 (id, data) VALUES (1, "First row")');
  });
  db.transaction(function (tx) {
  tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM file1', [], function (tx, results) {
  var len = results.rows.length, i , j;
  for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
  alert(results.rows.item(i).log1);
  alert(results.rows.item(i).log2);
  }
  }, null);
  }); 
  }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <h1>Example</h1>
  <p>Database</p>
  <input type="button" onclick="datab();">
  </body>
  </html>
```

When I execute this code its generating a error openDatabase is not defined. I have included phonegap jar file. What mistake I am doing? Please someone help.

Answer (score 0):

Which cordova version are you working on?
The cordova version in the link you have mentioned is quite old (1.4)
The current cordova version is 4.0

You need to use `window.openDatabase` instead of `openDatabase`. Also you need to wait for deviceReady event before calling the database function.

```
var db = window.openDatabase
```

Please see the link [here](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage) for more details.

**Edit 1:**
Have look at the below links for installing cordova.

http://thejackalofjavascript.com/phonegap-3-cli-setup-mac-windows/

http://coenraets.org/blog/cordova-phonegap-3-tutorial/

http://teusink.blogspot.in/2013/07/guide-phonegap-3-android-windows.html

http://sdk.revmobmobileadnetwork.com/phonegap_cordova.html

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide

[Phonegap Cordova installation Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035566/phonegap-cordova-installation-windows)

[PhoneGap 3.1.0 without node / npm and command line tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19020377/phonegap-3-1-0-without-node-npm-and-command-line-tools)

Comment: I just added phongap-1.4.1 jar file but Its still showing error. No  problem even I am using old version because only small table I want  where I can save file names[Only file not even content]. Please suggest me what else I can do. Or any other example

Comment: I never said that I am using 1.4.1. What I said that you are using 1.4.1 and u shud be using 4.0 version. Also I have edited my answer and provided you links on how to install the latest version of cordova.