# How do I install Phonegap 3.3 on Windows

Tags: android, ios, cordova

I just went to Phonegap and saw that I needed to install node.js to get started.

I did this, then followed the command line to install phonegap.

However, where is it? I don't see anything in my program files folder, I don't see Eclipse, and there's no documentation on what to do next on Phonegap's website. I don't understand why this instruction is so vague? What am I missing? And where did all those files I downloaded/installed go go?

Thanks

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035566/phonegap-cordova-installation-windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phonegap installation steps present on the official site are somewhat vaguely presented and hasn't been properly updated.

With respect to your question, I think this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/18751002/4277415 might help you out.

Cheers.

Comment: Wow great post. For what it's worth, they have done some updating on the install since I asked this question.

Answer (score 3):

```
Phonegap 3.3 installation there is no proper info in phonegap site. 

The reason of installing nodejs is, phonegap cordova are created as node modules.

Required Software’s:
Follow the steps.  1 Node Js  2 ANT  3 Android_sdk  4 JDK   

open command prompt: 
Follow the steps
C:\user\youruser>npm install -g phonegap
C:\user\youruser>npm install -g cordova
Set Environment variables:
Mycomputer -> Right Click -> properties -> Advance System settings -> Environment   
variables
set path for  1. Java JDK  2. Android SDK  3. ANT
C:\user\youruser>cordova platform add android
C:\user\youruser>phonegap create First-app
C:\user\youruser>cd First-app
C:\user\youruser>phonegap run android

Phonegap will be installed and apk will be created in bin folder. 

You will be getting 
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment..
[phonegap] using the local environment
[phonegap] compiling Android...
[phonegap] successfully compiled Android app
[phonegap] trying to install app onto device
[phonegap] successfully installed onto device

You can able to see phonegap modules in C:\Users\yourusername\AppData\Roaming\npm.

Hope this will be very helpful. Let me know if you face any issues.
```

Comment: Thanks for the information, this is helpful! Sorry I can not upvote yet, I don't know why there is a required thing before you can upvote.

Comment: No probs. have you installed.

Answer (score 0):

Install phonegap without any error : http://www.markupjavascript.com/2014/07/installing-phonegap-in-windows.html