# Cordova - Why is camera.getpicture not working?

Tags: android, cordova, camera

I am trying to get the camera feature to work. I am testing on a connected samsung galaxy tablet. The app launches successfully, but `navigator.camera.getpicture` does not launch the camera. Can you help with this?

Here are the steps I followed: I created a cordova hello project using the following steps on (Windows 7):

**PART A: (setup cordova)**
(steps from [this answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035566/phonegap-cordova-installation-windows/21744201#comment34500810_21744201) ):
    `C:> npm install -g cordova`

From command prompt, navigate to the folder you want to create your project using:

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
cd hello
Define the OS you want to suppport for example:

cordova platform add wp8
Install plugins (If needed). For example we want the following:

cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.device
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.camera
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.media-capture
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.media
```

**Part B: Add code for testing camera features**
(from code from [Cordova camera docs](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/2.9.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera))
Replaced index.html code with the following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Capture Photo</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.2.0.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

        var pictureSource;   // picture source
        var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value 

        // Wait for Cordova to connect with the device
        //
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

        // Cordova is ready to be used!
        //
        function onDeviceReady() {
            pictureSource = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
            destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType;
        }

        // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
        //
        function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
            // Uncomment to view the base64 encoded image data
            // console.log(imageData);

            // Get image handle
            //
            var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

            // Unhide image elements
            //
            smallImage.style.display = 'block';

            // Show the captured photo
            // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
            //
            smallImage.src = "data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
        }

        // Called when a photo is successfully retrieved
        //
        function onPhotoURISuccess(imageURI) {
            // Uncomment to view the image file URI 
            // console.log(imageURI);

            // Get image handle
            //
            var largeImage = document.getElementById('largeImage');

            // Unhide image elements
            //
            largeImage.style.display = 'block';

            // Show the captured photo
            // The inline CSS rules are used to resize the image
            //
            largeImage.src = imageURI;
        }

        // A button will call this function
        //
        function capturePhoto() {
            alert('taking photo');
            // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
            navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, {
                quality: 50,
                destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL
            });
        }

        // A button will call this function
        //
        function capturePhotoEdit() {
            // Take picture using device camera, allow edit, and retrieve image as base64-encoded string  
            navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, {
                quality: 20, allowEdit: true,
                destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL
            });
        }

        // A button will call this function
        //
        function getPhoto(source) {
            // Retrieve image file location from specified source
            navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, {
                quality: 50,
                destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
                sourceType: source
            });
        }

        // Called if something bad happens.
        // 
        function onFail(message) {
            alert('Failed because: ' + message);
        }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick="capturePhoto();">Capture Photo</button> <br>
    <button onclick="capturePhotoEdit();">Capture Editable Photo</button> <br>
    <button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY);">From Photo Library</button><br>
    <button onclick="getPhoto(pictureSource.SAVEDPHOTOALBUM);">From Photo Album</button><br>
    <img style="display:none;width:60px;height:60px;" id="smallImage" src="" />
    <img style="display:none;" id="largeImage" src="" />
  </body>
</html>
```

**Part C :Run the app on connected device (Samsung Galaxy tab)**

```
cordova run android
```

The app launches successfully on the tablet, BUT the buttons in index.html do not launch the camera. Why is this? I am not sure how to even debug this situation. Can you shed some light on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know why you have `src="cordova-2.2.0.js"`, simply change it to `src=cordova.js` and it should work.

For debugging have a look at `adb logcat`.

Comment: Yes, I spotted that same problem, shortly after posting the question. Nevertheless, thanks for looking over the code and answering.