# How to install plugin in cordova. There is no Plugin folder for cordova, only in phoneGap

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8

I have downloaded the latest Cordova 3.4.0-rc1. I can run it using Windows Phone emulator in Visual Studio 2013. Now how do I install plugin like Accelerometer, Battery that already included in the phoneGap framework? I cannot find the documentation about it. The reason why I use Cordova instead of phoneGap is because phoneGap has not updated their framework since 5th November 2013 and from what I have heard that there is not much different between these 2 frameworks [image: Cordova and phoneGap framework]

update my question:

I followed this step when installing cordova for Windows Phone 8 (without using terminal). I cannot figure out where is the plugin files in the template: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_platforms_wp8_index.md.html

The only solution (not that I want ) is that I have to use phoneGap instead of cordova. I'm trying to call the API to show device version such as console.log(device.version); but it doesn't work when using cordova because of missing plugin that needs to be installed manually but it does work on phoneGap. Any idea how to install Cordova for Windows Phone plugin manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have similar problem to this guy:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/LcBjwm5wypI

After searching and reading some posts, it seems like the current official documentation about setting up cordova is worst and useless. I solve this problem from this thread:

[Phonegap Cordova installation Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035566/phonegap-cordova-installation-windows)

Answer (score 0):

you just need to fire `cordova plugin add [plugin name]` in terminal and the plugin will be added for you.

What are the steps you followed to install cordova? Which OS are you using?

Also check inside your `www` folder, maybe the plugin folder is there.

Comment: I followed this step: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.0.0/guide_platforms_wp8_index.md.html and the OS that I'm using is Windows 8.1. I have checked in the www folder, there is no plugin folder.

Comment: in this link see 4. Review the project structure . The screenshot in it has `plugins` folder. Do you get this structure after creating the project?

Comment: Nope. I can confirm to you that there is no plugin or plugins folder in the latest framework (Cordova 3.4.0-rc1). that I have downloaded.

Comment: I have never tried cordova with windows. But as per documentation, the folder structure should contain plugins too. Try it from scratch.

Comment: I have tried from scratch, with the Cordova 3.0.0 as well. There is no plugin folder for Windows Phone 8..