# Phonegap execution fails with error: getaddrinfo EAGAIN

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, windows

I am new to phonegap and want to create a app for windows phone 8 using phonegap.

My system details:

`Windows 8 basic`
`6 GB RAM`

I have windows SDK preinstalled in my system.
I downloaded  node.js and ran the command:

```
  npm install -g phonegap
```

The installation initiallly threw errors since there were proxy settings setup for my system but the network was without proxy.
I removed the proxy by editing the config file using command:

```
  npm config edit
```

and tried again.The setup completed. However when I tried to execute the next command as mentioned [here](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface), it gives error:

```
 Error: getaddrinfo EAGAIN <br/>
 at errnoException (dns.js:37:11) <br/>
 at Object.onanswer [as complete] (dns.js:124:16)
```

I tried looking for solutions [here](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/2580) but did not reach one.
The environment is set up to use node and npm.

Comment: I am getting same error in Visual Studio 2013 while building the solution. Could someone help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems I was foolish to follow the rules when they were clearly meant to be broken :). After ignoring the documentation, I simply downloaded the [Phonegap master zip](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/archive/master.zip) from GitHub and ran `createtemplates.bat` located inside lib folder.

This will generate templates. Just copy whichever template you want into your `sdk` template folder and you are done.

For more info, see [Phonegap Cordova installation Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035566/phonegap-cordova-installation-windows).

Answer (score 0):

The EAGAIN means data is not currently available - maybe you can try once more with proper network settings. Also when you try, make sure all your network blocking agents (especially when working on a corporate machine) like the Symantec Firewall / End point protection is turned off. I believe it should then work fine.

Comment: Yeah i tried those all.Disabled antivirus, allowed node through firewall but it still wont work. The point is it worked fine for some time and I can see packages being downloaded but later on it always ends up in a error. I am on a personal machine.

Answer (score 0):

Updating the cordova cli separately should fix this issue:
    npm install -g cordova