# How to create and build a windows phone phonegap project?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7, cordova, windows-phone-8

I have developed a phonegap project for android platform and it is completed.Now I want to create a build of same project for windows platform. So I have followed the following link for reference,  http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/guide_getting-started_windows-phone-8_index.md.html but I stuck with issues.

My Specifications,
Windows-7 OS, cordova-3.5, Visual studio 2010, Windows phone SDK 7.1

I stuck with below points,

```
Download the latest copy of [PhoneGap and extract its contents. We will be working with the subfolder: lib\windows-phone-8\
copy the file CordovaWP8AppFull-x.x.x.zip to the folder : \My Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Templates\ProjectTemplates\
```

2.1. Building the template

Note: this step may not be required. If the lib\windows-phone directory already contains a file CordovaStarter-x.x.x.zip then you may skip this step ) In order to simplify the development process, Cordova comes with a Visual Studio template that allows creating a Cordova application rapidly. This template can be modified if needed and the below steps indicate how to proceed if you want to modify and re-generate the template.

```
Open the file lib\windows-phone\templates\standalone\CordovaSolution.sln in Visual Studio Express for Windows Phone
From the file menu, select 'Export Template...'
Choose template type 'Project template'
Give the exported template a name, ex. CordovaStarter-2.1.0 will produce CordovaStarter-2.1.0.zip
Optionally, you may add a description, icon image, and Preview image. These are what is displayed in Visual Studio in the 'New Project' dialog.-
Note: If you select ( 'Automatically import the template ... ') then you will not need to copy the .zip file over as outlined in step 2.
Press 'Finish'
```

I have installed the cordova from command line.

1) Where can I find the lib\windows-phone-8\CordovaWP8AppFull-x.x.x.zip folder in phonegap? I am unable to find the folder.

2) Also I am not able to find lib\windows-phone\templates\standalone\CordovaSolution.sln. Please help How to build my first project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In visual studio can you create the following projects CordovaWP8AppStandalone or Full solution?

If not you need to add the Visual Studio template here : C:\Users\YOURNAME\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Templates\ProjectTemplates

or Go to github and simply download the https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/archive/master.zip

Off Topic:
Have you tried to create a standard Windows Phone Html5 App and add your PhoneGap Code within this Html project?

EDIT:
you can download the latest version of cordova (for windows) 3.5.0 here: http://archive.apache.org/dist/cordova/platforms/cordova-windows-3.5.0.zip

EDIT bis:
here is the archives for all of the Cordova Versions: http://archive.apache.org/dist/cordova/

Edit 3:
Visual studio update with Cordova: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/somasegar/archive/2014/08/04/visual-studio-2013-update-3.aspx?utm_content=buffer4421b&utm_medium=social&utm_source=facebook.com&utm_campaign=buffer

Comment: I have a small dough @Damien, If I create a project using Cordova Windows 7 template will that app run in windows 8 phone? Is there any device target is there for windows so that we can specify our target devices.

Comment: @Precious  If you create a Windows Phone 7 Application, it will run on Windows Phone 7, 7.5, 8, 8.1 (so WP7 and higher devices), if you create a Windows Phone 8 Application it will only run on Windows Phone 8 and higher devices.

As of June 23rd WP 8 >= has 82% of the market and WP7.X has 17% so depending on your application you might want to target WP7 devices or not. 
Source: http://blog.adduplex.com/2014/06/adduplex-windows-phone-statistics.html

Comment: Thank you for your information. One more query, I have downloaded the cordova template from the following link, https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/archive/master.zip and added it under visual studio project template and it is working fine. But the issue is It is cordova 2.9 but the latest version is 3.5 how can I update that cordova template. Or do you have any other links for cordova template of version 3 or above ?

Comment: Yup you can try this link: http://archive.apache.org/dist/cordova/platforms/cordova-windows-3.5.0.zip or here to find all of the archives of Cordova:  http://archive.apache.org/dist/cordova/

Comment: Will try and let  you know @Damien

Answer (score 1):

The Phonegap documentation for Windows phone is really horrible. Finally I got the solution from the following link,

[Phonegap Cordova installation Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035566/phonegap-cordova-installation-windows)

Comment: Ok great! I didnt know installing phonegap with windows phone would be sure a bother!