# cordova error during build of android for PATH

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

please fine error in below image ant --version kindly provide some better information to setup cordova android on windows operating system

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQneE.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the following links on Cordova/Phonegap.

http://thejackalofjavascript.com/phonegap-3-cli-setup-mac-windows/

http://coenraets.org/blog/cordova-phonegap-3-tutorial/

http://teusink.blogspot.in/2013/07/guide-phonegap-3-android-windows.html

http://sdk.revmobmobileadnetwork.com/phonegap_cordova.html

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide

[Phonegap Cordova installation Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035566/phonegap-cordova-installation-windows)