# Running unix commands on windows cmd

Tags: android, windows, unix, cordova, cmd

i am currently trying to learn how to develop apps for android mobile phones using PhoneGap. i was able to get this book titled "PhoneGap 2x mobile application development". ths book is really nice and self explanatory but the problem i have is when the author want to create d project via the command line, he was using Unix commands because he is running a Unix PC. I am running Windows and to follow his commands using the CMD is a bit hard for me because i dont understand all of his commands.

Below was what he wrote:

```
mkdir $PROJECT_HOME
cd $PROJECT_HOME
mkdir Android iOS www
cd $PHONEGAP_HOME/lib/android/bin
./create $PROJECT_HOME/Android/QuizTime com.phonegaphotshot.
QuizTime QuizTime
cd $PHONEGAP_HOME/lib/ios/bin
./create $PROJECT_HOME/iOS com.phonegaphotshot.QuizTime QuizTime
cd $PROJECT_HOME
mkdir www/cordova
cp Android/QuizTime/assets/www/cordova-2.2.0.js www/cordova/
cordova-2.2.0-android.js
cp iOS/www/cordova-2.2.0.js www/cordova/cordova-2.2.0-ios.js
cd Android/QuizTime/assets
rm –rf www
ln –s ../../../www
cd ../../../iOS
rm –rf www
ln -s ../www
cd ..
cd www
cp –r $YASMF_DOWNLOAD/framework .
mkdir images models views style
cd ..
cd Android/QuizTime/src/com/phonegaphotshot/QuizTime
edit QuizTime.java
Change "index.html" to "index_android.html"
Save the file.
cd $PROJECT_HOME/iOS/QuizTime
```

can someone tell me how to do this on the windows cmd. i know what mkdir is but i need a total description and if possible a translation following that if you were to do this on a windows cmd.

Comment: have you tried checking out google for the commands you don't recognize? Most of these are fairly close to windows. Be more specific for what you don't understand.

Comment: the "cp" which i am guessing is "copy" on windows cmd. i just need some one who could translate all that into windows command if he sees something like that. i am not a Unix user but i'm doing my best trying to understand him. like for example where he wrote "cd $PHONEGAP_HOME/lib/android/bin
./create $PROJECT_HOME/Android/QuizTime com.phonegaphotshot.
QuizTime QuizTime, i'm gussing he wants me to create a sub-folder within the android/bin folder. i just need help here

Comment: There really isn't any guessing on cp. You can easily type in "unix command cp" to get the result. For the `./create` that's a bit harder but just means run the script create with the options `$PROJECT_HOME/iOS com.phonegaphotshot.QuizTime QuizTime`. You need to read a tutorial on basic unix command line. This doesn't really belong in stack overflow and should probably go to the unix group, but without some effort on your part to help yourself I suspect they will probably close the ticket as well.

Answer (score 1):

I forgot to mention one simple fact. You CAN NOT RUN the unix commands over Windows DOS/CMD
check this link. It gives direct co-relation between dos and unix commands. hope this helps.
http://www.tldp.org/LDP/intro-linux/html/app2.html

or better still, check this 
http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/unix_for_dos_users.html

Once you get the different commands, guess it should not be hard for you to write it in DOS.
Note: The "create" command is part of phonegap/cordova apis..

Also, check this link: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.1.0/guide_command-line_index.md.html

Here is a snapshot of the code converted:

```
 -- make directory ---
 C:\> mkdir PROJECT_HOME
 -- go to the directory you created ---
 cd PROJECT_HOME
-- make directories inside ---
C:\PROJECT_HOME> mkdir Android
C:\PROJECT_HOME> mkdir iOS
C:\PROJECT_HOME> mkdir www
-- now navigate to the bin directory- ---
C:\PROJECT_HOME> cd \lib\android\bin
-- now you basically runn the create command, am hereby just putting in what you wrote ---
C:\PROJECt_HOME\lib\android\bin>create \PROJECT_HOME\Android\QuizTime com.phonegaphotshot.QuizTime QuizTime
----- do same for the ios------------
-------make dir for cordova -------
C:\PROJECT_HOME> cd www
C:\PROJECT_HOME\www> mkdir cordova
--then you have to copy the contents of one directory to another, to copy everyrthin in directory recursively, use xcopy-----------
C:\PROJECT_HOME> XCOPY Android\QuizTime\assets\www\cordova-2.2.0.js www\cordova\cordova-2.2.0-android.js
```

Comment: i have seen the link and it helps but i am still confused with some parts of the Unix commands he wrote. could you help translate it for me if you were to follow him and you are using a windows pc? i really need to get this started

Comment: @Andrecon I can only guide a bit. check the edit above.

Comment: I do not know, but may i know the reason for downvote for the answer? Am just trying to guide the person in right direction. Not a great deal, but I would love to know the reasoning behind.

Comment: i'll try your suggestion and get back to u. Thanks and you will have my vote if it works

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a quite old question but anyway, have you ever tried a terminal emulator? Try [Console](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/files/). It's a free terminal emulator for windows.

and to get to know what a command does type

```
man <command>
```

in the terminal.

Answer (score 0):

The book "PhoneGap 2x mobile application development" is quite old. The phonegap/cordova development has  changed quite a bit from 3x onwards. The current/latest version is 4x.

Below are the links pertaining to phonegap/cordova 3x which will work for 3x and 4x versions.

hope it helps.

http://thejackalofjavascript.com/phonegap-3-cli-setup-mac-windows/

http://coenraets.org/blog/cordova-phonegap-3-tutorial/

http://teusink.blogspot.in/2013/07/guide-phonegap-3-android-windows.html

http://sdk.revmobmobileadnetwork.com/phonegap_cordova.html

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide

[Phonegap Cordova installation Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035566/phonegap-cordova-installation-windows)

Answer (score 0):

If you install Cygwin you can use unix commands on Windows CMD as you can see on this website https://lifehacker.com/362316/use-unix-commands-in-windows-built-in-command-prompt

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is possible to run UNIX commands on Windows. Have a look at all of the UNIX commands compiled for Windows in this GitHub repository: https://github.com/George-Ogden/UNIX