# How to start with phonegap - installation

Tags: android, cordova, installation

I have some simple question becuse phonegap docs is so hard to understand, also some tutorial for first basic steps are welcome.

1. Everything what I need to install to use phonegap?
2. Where is the folder of instaled phonegap?
3. How to start instalation (CMD, node.js) ?

I type in CMD:

```
C:\> npm install -g phonegap
```

and I get:

[image]

What is the next step? Please help?

Answer (score 1):

Its not an error its just a warning.

It means its working, next type in the following in your command prompt

`phonegap create myapp com.cordovaprogramming.hello Hello`

This will create a myapp folder writes the application ID as com.cordovaprogramming.hello to the application’s configuration file and allows you to have an Hello as an application name.

For more information check http://www.kodkillerz.com/using-cordova-command-line-interface/

That is for cordova, just replace cordova with phonegap and all will work fine.

Thanks

Comment: o I install phonegap and cordova, what that sreen means: imgur.com/zryesD7 What is the error here?

Comment: Did you set the environment variables after you installed the Android SDK. LIke adding the tools, build-tools and platform tools to the PATH variable inside environment variables. Details here:
http://www.kodkillerz.com/getting-started-android-developer-tools-cordova/

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/wDTzdni.png now I install everything and I get this screen: http://i.imgur.com/wDTzdni.png

Comment: npm install -g phonegap

Comment: i install phonegap, see the image of cmd

Comment: Do you have this in your System environment variable path :
C:\Program Files\nodejs\
Check this for details
http://www.kodkillerz.com/install-nodejs/

Comment: I add this to system environment but again I get: http://i.imgur.com/qh1hjPK.png - phonegap is not recognized ...

Comment: Send me a screen shot of you program files folder where you installed nodejs, and when you run npm install -g phonegap

Answer (score 1):

you can refer the below article for installing Phonegap/Cordova.

http://thejackalofjavascript.com/phonegap-3-cli-setup-mac-windows/

http://coenraets.org/blog/cordova-phonegap-3-tutorial/

http://teusink.blogspot.in/2013/07/guide-phonegap-3-android-windows.html

http://sdk.revmobmobileadnetwork.com/phonegap_cordova.html

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide

[Phonegap Cordova installation Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035566/phonegap-cordova-installation-windows)

Comment: so I install phonegap and cordova, what that sreen means: http://imgur.com/zryesD7 What is the error here?

Comment: James D: it means that you need to set your PATH environment variable or the commands won't find them. Here's how you do that: http://iphonedevlog.wordpress.com/2014/10/30/setting-up-your-developmemt-environment-for-cordovaphonegap-android-projects/