# The Cordova Contacts API is inaccessible

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I am trying to access Cordova Contacts API to access the device contact details but i am not able to get the details .I have added the reference of `Cordova.js` and have added below in `Conf.xml` ..

```
<feature name="Contacts">
<param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.contacts.ContactManager" />
</feature>
```

and i have given permission in `AndroidManifest.xml` file too..

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
```

Still on running my application in the `OnLoad()` event function only i am getting this error because of `undefined` ..Here is the code..

```
function onLoad() {
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);
$("#searchby_chooser_ok_button").bind ("click", searchByCriteria); 

if (typeof Contact === "undefined") {
    getElement("contacts_list").innerHTML = "<p>The Cordova Contacts API is inaccessible</p>";
}
}
```

I tried my level best to search on web in vain only .Is there any specific file that i need to add into the project?..Please help me to resolve this ..Thanks..Here is my project directory structure

[image: Project Directory]

Comment: this is a [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27057942/typeof-contact-undefined-error-message)

Comment: @frank Dear Sir,, I tried my best to find out the solution for this but not succeeded ..Needed your help to resolve this ..Please help me.I am not able to find out the issue that is creating this ..

Comment: @frank Is there anything that i am missing or any issue with the Cordova ..i tried everything that i got from web but not success ..I added my project directory image also..Please have a look ..Thanks..

Comment: please refer to the documentation on contacts plugin over [here](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts/blob/master/doc/index.md). In short you first need to add contacts plugin to your project using the following command `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.contacts` and than wait for `deviceready` event before using the contacts object i.e `navigator.contacts`. Read documentation for further info

Comment: @frank OK..I have created This Phonegap application from command prompt..Now in it how can i add `contacts pluging` by the command that you mentioned..

Comment: you have to go to the project directory `( i.e cd <your Project dir> )` and then type the `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.contacts` command on the prompt. This will automatically add the plugin to your project. You need not change `AndroidManifest.xml` or `config.xml` file, this will be changed by the command.

Comment: @frank Ok .I got you words dear.But as i am creating my project from `phonegap2.9.0` and from Command Prompt as soon as i type `cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.contacts` i get error as `Cordova is not recognised as an internal or External Command`.Why is this and How to reolve this ?

Comment: @frank Here is the full path of my variables `%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0\bin;E:\adt-bundle-windows-x86\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\platform-tools;E:\adt-bundle-windows-x86\adt-bundle-windows-x86\sdk\tools;C:\Program Files (x86)\WinAnt\bin`

Comment: if you are using `phonegap` for your project than you need to replace keyword `cordova` with `phonegap` i.e `phonegap plugin add org.apache.cordova.contacts`.

Comment: @frank Will there be any issue in Using `phonegap` instead of `Cordova` as you said..Also i tried the `phonegap plugin add org.apache.cordova.contacts` Command in my OS CMD but it is giving same error as `not recognised command`

Comment: if that is the case than i would suggest that you should start creating your projects from start using the cordova commands instead of phonegap. What is the reason for creating a phonegap project instead of cordova?

Comment: @frank No Specific reason sir .Will you please tell me how to create project from `Cordova` command because when i tried it on OS CMD i am getting `Not recognised Command`

Comment: @frank Thank you sir for your usefull link.I have one more doubt. As i downloaded the `Phonegap` file from phonegap.com and building the project files from there ..Will there be any [problem i nthis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the following links for phonegap/cordova project.

http://thejackalofjavascript.com/phonegap-3-cli-setup-mac-windows/

http://coenraets.org/blog/cordova-phonegap-3-tutorial/

http://teusink.blogspot.in/2013/07/guide-phonegap-3-android-windows.html

http://sdk.revmobmobileadnetwork.com/phonegap_cordova.html

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide

[Phonegap Cordova installation Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035566/phonegap-cordova-installation-windows)