# Latest version of phonegap for native apps

Tags: cordova, aptana, aptana3

I want to use the Phonegap to develop native apps.

I try to download the latest version but when I go to the official page of [phonegap installation page](http://phonegap.com/install/) I see that the latest version is 2.9.1 from November 2013. Is there any newer version?

Also how can I run the phonegap. Is there any specific IDE for this?
The only way I found is from aptana studio

Answer (score 1):

Read better on http://phonegap.com/install/

When cordova 3 arrived, they started distributing phonegap as a node package

So, install node and then execute this command

```
npm install -g phonegap
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. That's why when I try to include here the phonegap tag it gives me the cordova tag.

Answer (score 0):

Below are the links for phonegap/cordova development.

ttp://thejackalofjavascript.com/phonegap-3-cli-setup-mac-windows/

http://coenraets.org/blog/cordova-phonegap-3-tutorial/

http://teusink.blogspot.in/2013/07/guide-phonegap-3-android-windows.html

http://sdk.revmobmobileadnetwork.com/phonegap_cordova.html

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_platforms_android_index.md.html#Android%20Platform%20Guide

[Phonegap Cordova installation Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18035566/phonegap-cordova-installation-windows)

Comment: thank you for those all useful links. As I can understand now it is not phonegap but apache cordova which is the descendant of phonegap?

Comment: Phonegap was developed by Adobe, which latter on was given to the open source community, which is now called cordova. Phonegap and cordova are the same, Phonegap internally uses corodva. Phonegap allows you to build the Apps online, whereas cordova is used for building Apps locally. if you want to use Adobe build services (build.phonegap.com) which provides **online** building of your phonegap application, than you should use `phonegap` command. If you are building locally (i.e in your own desktop) you need to use `cordova` command.