# Cordova error; Android Home windows, cmd

Tags: android, cordova, cmd

i´m trying to run my cordova application on my device, i already add the platform android to my project.
i´m doing all trought cmd.
but i got an error as you can see on the following picture.

Can you tell me what´s wrong? how can i fix it please?[image]

i can run on browser with "cordova run browser", but it doesn´t work for android. it show me this error, and i can´t find a solution.

Comment: Setup ur path of SDK Android home in settings

Comment: how do i do that can you specify?or show me an example. please it would help me alot.

Answer (score 1):

> Can you tell me what´s wrong? how can i fix it please?

Cordova couldn't find Android SDK home in your computer. If you've already installed SDK, so make sure environmental variable `ANDROID_HOME` points exactly to the root of SDK directory.

> i can run on browser with "cordova run browser",

No you can't run Android apps on browsers. You have two options:

- Android emulator : `run --emulator`
- Real Android devices connected via USB : `run --device`

More information:

- https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/4.0.0/guide/platforms/android/

Answer (score 0):

> for Windows 7 Computer -> (rightclick) properties -> Advanced System
> setting. At Advanced tab you will see Environment variables (open it)
>
> In the system properties window click the environment variables button.
>
> Select the PATH variable from the System variables section. Select the Edit button. You need to add the path to your Android SDK platform-tools and tools directory. For Example: D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219\sdk\platform-tools;D:\adt-bundle-windows-x86_64-20130219\sdk\tools Save your Edit. Close the Environment Variable dialog.

Refer here :

[See here for complete setup of environment](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21100075/4609016)

Comment: i follow what you said.  But now i got an error saying that "ANDROID_HOME" has  set to non-existent path "after that shows the both path that you told me to put."

Comment: "ANDROID_HOME" has set to non-existent path  "c:/name/../tools ; c:.... plataform-tools"